# Formatting chatroom with Divs or with table (tr,td)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made a chatroom where a  user types his message into textarea,then the message is sent to the PHP file where it creates an html around the message and then it writes it into a file called `log.html`. It also takes the users username and his profile picture.

So previously I had my code looking like this :

```
<div class='msgln'>

    <ul>
        <li class='float'><img src='$someimg'></li>
        <li class='username_chatroom'><b>username</b></li>
        <li class='text_chatroom'><span class='text_span'>Random text</span><li>


    </ul>


</div>
```

Does it make more sense converting the divs to table td ,tr for easier formatting? Would the code then look like this? :

```
<tr class='tr_chat'>
        <td class='img_chat'><img src='$someimg'></td>
        <td class='usr_chat'><b>username</b></td>
        <td class='msg_chat'>Text text text</td>    
</tr>
```

The only other question I then have is, when I create the file in which this html will be, do I need to define the end of the table? Because when I create a file I can define at the beginning  `<table>` but I can't end it, because the code would go like this then:

```
      <table>
      </table>
      <tr class='tr_chat'>
      <td class='img_chat'><img src='$someimg'></td>
      <td class='usr_chat'><b>username</b></td>
      <td class='msg_chat'>Text text text</td>  
      </tr>
```

So, is it better to use tables instead of divs for formatting, and if so.. do I need to define the end of a table?

Comment: **Don't use tables for layout.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it make more sense converting the divs to table td ,tr for easier formatting?

No, but it does make sense to convert to a table because the data is tabular in nature.

Each item in a row has something in common (it is a specific message and the metadata about it).

Each column has something in common (you have sensible headings you can give them).

That is what tables are for.

> The only other question i then have is , when i create the file in which this html will be, do i need to define the end of the table??

Yes. The end tag for the table element is mandatory.

> Because when i create a file i can define at the beggining but i cant end it,because the code would go like this then

Your problem is that you are trying to use HTML as your database.

Use a real database instead. Generate the HTML from it on demand.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer  Quentin ,the answer is exactly what i was looking for :)